# Can a blade's Affinity Chart reward be earned before completing the previous level?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I recently unlocked level 3 of Dromarch's Affinity Chart. Level 2 of the Raging Tiger skill is incomplete with a hidden unlock condition of "???" while level 3's condition is visible as "Use Raging Tiger (0/11)".

Is it possible to complete a blade's level 3 Affinity Chart reward before completing the level 2 reward? Will progress towards level 3 count if I haven't completed level 2?

[image: Dromarch's level 3 affinity reward for Raging Tiger]

Comment: Found a strange overlap of conditions on Gorg's Ability Chart. FTL level 1's condition is "Help an incapacitated ally (0/3)" while level 2 has "Help an incapacitated ally (0/2)".

Comment: Well, you can easily try this by yourself. But I don't think helping an incapacitated ally should overlap, there would be no reason to make a lower request for a higher skill level otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to complete a blade's level 3 Affinity Chart reward before completing the level 2 reward?

While my current save is not in a really good spot to test this, but I'm going with No. While reviewing Myrtha's affinity chart, I have her level 4 nodes unlocked. As you can see in the screenshots below, she has a handful for level 2 and 3 not completed. I know for a fact I've used Lightning Buster and Photo Edge a numerous amount of times after unlocking these nodes, but yet they do not any progression towards completion.

[image: Mythra Node 1] [image: Mythra Node 1]

> Will progress towards level 3 count if I haven't completed level 2?

The answer to this one is that it depends on the node. As shown above, progression towards level 3 nodes does not count if level 2 is not completed. However, there are some nodes that have "Previous instances count toward total" as sub-text

[image: Vale node 3]

Comment: I was able to confirm that level 3 rewards cannot be unlocked before level 2. I also noted a few extra things: •Affinity rewards for drivers must also be unlocked in level-order. •Poppi α's affinity chart rewards for Tiger! Tiger! high scores are retroactive, despite not being listed as such. (Play 1 round of Tiger! Tiger! and the condition will unlock based on previous high scores). •If you've completed a level 2 condition, progress towards the level 3 condition won't count until you check that blade's Affinity chart